# str.cat ignores `na_rep` parameter?

Tags: python, pandas

The parameter `na_rep` doesn't have expected effect. It's
ignored, actually.

My MRE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'x': ['', 'b', 1, 2, 3, 'a'], 
                   'y': [1, 4, 2, np.nan, 4, 7],
                   'z': [3, 4, 55, 3, 2, 4]})
df['y'].astype(str).str.cat(df['x'].astype(str), sep="_&_")
df['y'].astype(str).str.cat(df['x'].astype(str), sep="_&_", na_rep="MISSING")
```

The output from the last call is same as one before:

```
0     1.0_&_
1    4.0_&_b
2    2.0_&_1
3    nan_&_2
4    4.0_&_3
5    7.0_&_a
Name: y, dtype: object
```

I've run the examples with the documentation for Pandas and I confirm their examples do work.  Why doesn't mine work?

I'm working with Pandas 1.4.4 in Debian Linux.

Comment: raise a bug report on pandas github issues page

Comment: There is already an old one: https://github.com/rapidsai/cudf/issues/4349

Comment: That is a related issue on github, but not exactly the same.  That one is about na_rep='', a blank, while I see the thing does not work for any replacement.

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that when converting `y` to string, `NaN` basically becomes `nan`, which is a string representation of `NaN` and not `NaN` itself.

Therefore, `na_rep` does not work, because it is supposed to operate on actual `NaN` values and not on its string representation!

So, you should ideally convert to string while preserving `NaNs`.

One way to do this could be to use:

`pd.Series.astype('string')` instead of `pd.Series.astype(str)`.

So, you'd get:

```py
df['y'].astype('string').str.cat(df['x'].astype('string'), sep='_&_', na_rep='MISSING')
```

Alternatively, you can even convert like this:

```py
df['y'] = df['y'].dropna().astype(str) # original NaNs are not touched due to index alignment
df['y'].str.cat(df['x'].astype(str), sep="_&_") # be sure to do the same for X in case NaNs are there too
```

Any other way to convert the Series to string while preserving `NaN` values should be expected to work as well.

Comment: Brilliant and thorough. Just how `string` is different that `str` in `astype` method?

Comment: Thanks @AnoushiravanR! I think their differences are summed up here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html#behavior-differences

Comment: Thanks, will try.  Although using 'string' in the past has caused trouble because we've run into other functions that don't work the same as with 'str'.  'string' creates a different dtype.  Run this to see:
```
x = pd.Series([1, 2, pd.NA]);
x.astype(str);
x.astype('string');
```
The 'string' variant creates a new 'string' dtype, which is not fully integrated with some existing functions that you run into.  But I'm not too worried.  Also, setting a missing as `pd.NA` or `np.nan` has different effects.

Comment: I see. That's why I have added a second way that still uses `str` and maintains NaNs as they were! @pauljohn32